# youtube full screen not working

Tags: javascript, android, webview, youtube, android-webview

I've spent a lot of hours looking for good full screen information for videos like youtube to activate full screen. I found a lot of info but the problem is that I am new in the android world. I have a Web View app and the youtube video starts and plays and works great and redirects me but the problem is the full screen, I can't get it to work. My files look like this, sorry I post all in.

I am sorry that I'm asking a question that a lot of people have asked on stack overflow but nowhere have i found the right information to get it to work. If somebody can, help me please.

If I must create a new file please tell me.

Thank you in advance.

```
    package com.example.qrcodegenrate;

    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ActivityManager;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings.RenderPriority;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import apppack.com.R;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") public class GenerateQRCodeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

       private ProgressBar progressBar;

       @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
       WebView mWebView = null;
       @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

             Bitmap iconBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.launcher_icon);
             ActivityManager.TaskDescription td = new ActivityManager.TaskDescription(null, iconBitmap,Color.rgb(77,195,241));
             setTaskDescription(td);
             iconBitmap.recycle();

          }     

          requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
          getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);     

          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress1);
          playVideo();      

          ImageButton button2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
          ImageButton button5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button5);
          button2.setOnClickListener(this);
          button5.setOnClickListener(this);

       }

       private void playVideo() {
          try {
             mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
             mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
             mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                }       

             });
             mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                   super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);

                }       

             });
             WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
             webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
             mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
             mWebView.requestFocusFromTouch();
             mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View mView, MotionEvent event) {
                   switch (event.getAction()) {
                      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                         try {
                            if (!mView.hasFocus()) {
                               mView.requestFocus();
                            }
                         } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                         }
                         break;

                   }
                   return false;
                }
             });
             mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
             mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
             mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4dc3f1"));

             mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
             mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
             webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

             mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientDemo());
             mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClientDemo(){
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                   super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);

                }

             });

             mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
             mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
             mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

             //    mWebView.loadUrl(URL);
             mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/apapack/home/index.html");
             mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
             mWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
             mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
             mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
             mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
             mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
             mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
             mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
             mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
             mWebView.getSettings().getPluginState();       
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }

    //    mWebView.loadUrl(URL);        
          getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
       }        

       private class WebViewClientDemo extends WebViewClient {      

          @Override
          public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
             view.loadUrl(url);

             return true;
          }
          @Override
          public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
             super.onPageFinished(view, url);
             progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

          }

          @Override
          public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
             super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
             progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

          }
       }
       private class WebChromeClientDemo extends WebChromeClient {
          public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

          }
       }        

       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
          getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
          return true;
       }        

       private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {      

          @Override
          public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
          {
             if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                      Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
             }else if(url.startsWith("http://") || url.startsWith("https://www.youtube.com/")) {
                mWebView.loadUrl(url);
             }      

          @Override
          public void onScaleChanged(WebView view, float oldScale, float newScale) {
             if (view != null) {
                view.invalidate();
             }
          }
          @Override
          public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                               String description, String failingUrl) {
             view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/nointernet.html");
          }
       }    

       public void onClick(View v) {

          switch (v.getId()) {  

             case R.id.button2:

                Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                break;

             case R.id.button5:
                mWebView.goBack();
                break;
             // More buttons go here (if any) ...
          }

       }

       public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
          if (requestCode == 0) {
             if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                Log.i("Barcode Result", contents);
                mWebView.loadUrl(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));

                //Intent i1 = new Intent(QRCodeSampleActivity.this, webclass.class);
                //startActivity(i1);
                // Handle successful scan
             } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Handle cancel
                Log.i("Barcode Result","Result canceled");
             }
          }
       }

       public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
          if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
             switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                   if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                      mWebView.goBack();
                   } else {
                      finish();
                   }
                   return true;
             }

          }
          return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
       }        

    }
```

**activity_main.xml file looks like this**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        style="android:textViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#f2f2f2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPlayVideo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Play" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/qrcode_v" />

            <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:maxHeight="2dip"
        android:minHeight="4dip"
        android:progress="0"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/greenprogress" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/back_button" />


        <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/my_progress_indeterminate"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

     </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have this in your androidManifest.xml `<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">`

Comment: yes  i have this in my androidManifest.xml but  nothing work thets dose not show the fullscreen buton from youtube

Comment: did ju know som codes thets let my webvie show full screen ?

Comment: No because you lock your screen to portrait mode. I can suggest you controle if the link is youtube so yes. Open the Youtube app instead.